# capybara assert attributes of an element

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I'm using RSpec2 and Capybara for acceptance testing.

I would like to assert that link is disabled or not in Capybara. How can I do this?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

How are you disabling the link? Is it a class you're adding? An attribute?

```
# Check for a link that has a "disabled" class:
page.should have_css("a.my_link.disabled")
page.should have_xpath("//a[@class='disabled']")

# Check for a link that has a "disabled" attribute:
page.should have_css("a.my_link[disabled]")
page.should have_xpath("//a[@class='disabled' and @disabled='disabled']")

# Check that the element is visible
find("a.my_link").should be_visible
find(:xpath, "//a[@class='disabled']").should be_visible
```

*The actual xpath selectors may be incorrect. I don't use xpath often!*

Comment: Thanks @idlefingers , I want to assert using xpath too. How can I do so?

Comment: I've updated my answer. If the xpath selectors are wrong, you'll have to do some googling or open a new question.

Comment: Note that this won't work for view testing, as capybara isn't made to work with views.  (Webrat is.)

Answer (score 147):

Another simple solution is to access the HTML attribute you are looking for with `[]`:

```
find('#my_element')['class']
# => "highlighted clearfix some_other_css_class"

find('a#my_element')['href']
# => "http://example.com

# or in general, find any attribute, even if it does not exist
find('a#my_element')['no_such_attribute']
# => ""
```

Note that `Capybara` will automatically try to wait for asynchronous requests to finish, but it may not work in some cases:

- http://www.elabs.se/blog/53-why-wait_until-was-removed-from-capybara

Here is one workaround if you are having trouble with assertions on elements that are updated asynchronously:

- http://robots.thoughtbot.com/automatically-wait-for-ajax-with-capybara

Comment: I've got a string with the css location, eg. `find('a#my_element[href]')`, would it be possible to retrieve the value of this attribute? Trying with expressions like `find('a#my_element[href]').value` but doesn't seem to work :(

Comment: @mickael Try `find('a#my_element[href]').text` or `find('a#my_element[href]').native` . Let me know if either of those give the results you expect.

Comment: I realise that these comments are really old, but used it this way: page.find('#my_element')['href="<href_value>"'] and it worked a treat

Comment: This will not wait for the query to become true if you want to make an assertion about an asynchronous change.

Comment: Thanks @sj26, I updated the answer with some info on asynchronous updates.

Answer (score 4):

It was a bit messy to find out the correct xpath, here is the correct one,
using capybara 0.4.1.1

```
# <a href="/clowns?ordered_by=clumsyness" class="weep">View Clowns</a>  

page.should have_xpath("//a[@class='weep'][@href='/clowns?ordered_by=clumsyness']", :text => "View Clowns")
```

If you only have a link without a class, use

```
page.should have_link('View Clowns', :href => '/clowns?ordered_by=clumsyness')
```

Something like this will sadly not work:

```
page.should have_link('This will not work!', :href => '/clowns?ordered_by=clumsyness', :class => "weep")
```

The class option will be ignored.

Answer (score 4):

I recommend using `have_link` and `find_link(name)[:disabled]` in two separate assertions. While performing the second assertion alone is simpler, this makes error messages about missing links look nicer, making your test results easier to read.

```
expect(page).to have_link "Example"
expect(find_link("Example")[:disabled]).to be false
```

Note that `"Example"` can be changed to the name or id of the link.

Answer (score 1):

```
page.should have_link('It will work this way!', {:href => '/clowns?ordered_by=clumsyness', :class => "smile"})
```

have_link expects a hash of options which is empty if you do not provide any. You can specify any attributes the link should have - just make sure you pass all the options in ONE hash.

Hope this helps

PS: For attributes like data-method you have to pass the attribute name as a string since the hyphen breaks the symbol.

Comment: [It never worked](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/issues/1016#issuecomment-15020730) and doesn't work with Capybara. I don't know why 9 people upvoted this.

Comment: This no longer works in Capybara 2.  Folks using Capybara < 2 can use the above

Comment: @Tian it didn't work in Capybara < 2. I suggest you to downvote this answer.

Comment: `class:` is not valid

Comment: you can not specify any attributes this way, only a certain allow-listed subset, including :href, :title, :alt, and :class. Class does work though!

Answer (score 1):

Whenever possible, you should try to use the Capybara provided wrappers which will work more consistently across drivers.

For the particular case of `disabled`, a wrapper was introduced in 2.1: https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/blob/fc56557a5463b9d944207f2efa401faa5b49d9ef/History.md#version-210

If you use it, you will get sensible results on both RackTest and Poltergeist:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="disabled-false"            ></div>
<input type="text" id="disabled-true"     disabled></div>
<input type="text" id="disabled-js-true"          ></div>
<input type="text" id="disabled-js-false" disabled></div>
<script>
  document.getElementById('disabled-js-true').disabled = true
  document.getElementById('disabled-js-false').disabled = false
</script>
```

Tests:

```
!all(:field, 'disabled-false',    disabled: false).empty? or raise
 all(:field, 'disabled-false',    disabled: true ).empty? or raise
 all(:field, 'disabled-true',     disabled: false).empty? or raise
!all(:field, 'disabled-true',     disabled: true ).empty? or raise
 all(:field, 'disabled-js-true',  disabled: true ).empty? or raise
 all(:field, 'disabled-js-false', disabled: false).empty? or raise

Capybara.current_driver = :poltergeist
!all(:field, 'disabled-false',    disabled: false).empty? or raise
 all(:field, 'disabled-false',    disabled: true ).empty? or raise
 all(:field, 'disabled-true',     disabled: false).empty? or raise
!all(:field, 'disabled-true',     disabled: true ).empty? or raise
!all(:field, 'disabled-js-true',  disabled: true ).empty? or raise
!all(:field, 'disabled-js-false', disabled: false).empty? or raise
```

Note how by using this instead of CSS selectors, the Javascript tests will work without any changes if you start using a Js capable driver.

Runnable test file [here](https://github.com/cirosantilli/ruby-cheat/blob/f2bbc981147fec1630e29b742a1a9fa215bc3709/capybara/main.rb#L278).

Answer (score 1):

Simply you can use `page.has_css?` method

```
page.has_css?('.class_name')
```

this will return `true` if element exists.

**Do some action based on validation.**

```
page.has_css?('.class_name') do
  #some code
end
```

Comment: In an RSpec example, the validation block can be silently ignored by accident, so make sure it's passed to the matcher and not the expect: `expect(page).to(have_css('.class_name') { |element| ... })`

Answer (score 0):

**bowsersenior**, thanks for a hint

> Another simple solution is to access the HTML attribute you are looking for with []

Here is an example:

```
let(:action_items) { page.find('div.action_items') }

it "action items displayed as buttons" do
  action_items.all(:css, 'a').each do |ai|
    expect(ai[:class]).to match(/btn/)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Rspec3's syntax i did it this way:

```
expect(page).not_to have_selector(:link_or_button, 'Click here')
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [the docs](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara/Node/Element#[]-instance_method) you can use the [attribute] accessor syntax:

```
find('#selector')['class'] => "form-control text optional disabled"
```

For disabled, you could also do this:

```
expect(find('#selector').disabled?).to be(true)
```