# How to make Capybara check for visibility after some JS has run?

Tags: ruby, rspec, capybara, integration-testing

After loading a page I have code that runs and hides and shows various items based on data returned by an xhr.

My integration test looks something like this:

```
it "should not show the blah" do
    page.find('#blah').visible?.should be_true
end
```

When I manually go to the page in the context this test runs, #blah is *not* visible as I expect. I suspect that Capybara is looking at the initial state of the page (invisible in this case), evaluating the state of the DOM and failing the test before the JS runs.

Yes, I set the `:js => true` on the containing describe block :)

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated! I'm hoping I don't have to put an intentional delay in here, that feels flaky and will slow things down.

Comment: What is the driver? What is the expected HTML once the XHR finished?

Answer (score 139, accepted):

I think that the `find` statement here is the one with the implicit wait, so Capybara will wait until the element is on the page, but won't wait for it to become visible.

Here, you would want Capybara to wait for the visible element to appear, which should be achievable by specifying the `visible` option:

```
expect(page).to have_selector('#blah', visible: true)
```

I haven't tried it, but the `ignore_hidden_elements` configuration option  might be useful here as well, if you wanted `find` to always wait for visible elements.

Comment: in case anyone initially misses @Kevin's note (like me), you must have `js:true` on the containing block for this to work.

Comment: This is awesome. It helped me get to: `expect(page).to have_selector('#flash-message', visible: false, text: "Signed in Successfully")` -- thanks for posting this answer

Comment: The visible option had no effect for me when testing the visibility of a jquery slide down element.  I had to use expect(find('#blah').visible?).to be_falsey.

Comment: I want something like is_visible? then do that else do something else

Answer (score 37):

This is another way to do it that works perfectly fine for me:

```
find(:css, "#some_element").should be_visible
```

Especially for more complex finds, such as

```
find(:css, "#comment_stream_list li[data-id='#{@id3}']").should_not be_visible
```

which would assert that an element has been hidden.

Comment: The `should_not be_visible` doesn't look good to me as Capybara run `wait_until { base.visible? }` when Element#visible? being invoked.

Comment: @phng-nguyn, #wait_until has been removed from recent versions of Capybara.

Comment: This is actually a better variant than the "page.should have_selector ...", because in case if a failing text, it's would say that the element is actually invisible explicitly, whereas the mentioned variant just evokes 'there were no matches' error, that is  a little bit frustrating.

Comment: This is not the same as the accepted solution. For this code, Capybara will only wait until the element is in the DOM, and then check visibility immediately. If you're expecting the visibility to change, this can add a race condition to the specs.

Comment: Does anybody know if `.should_not be_visible` covers `display: none` set by jQuery? It doesn't seem to work for me.

Answer (score 20):

If you want to check that an element is on the page but is not visible, `visible: false` won't work as you might expect. Had me stumped for a bit.

Here's how to do it:

```
# assert element is present, regardless of visibility
page.should have_css('#some_element', :visible => false)
# assert visible element is not present
page.should have_no_css('#some_element', :visible => true)
```

Comment: You can't use `should_not` with capybara, because of ajax

Comment: @Marc-AndréLafortune, to test ajax with capybara use Capybara.javascript_driver.

Comment: with javascript_drive, `have_css` will wait for your whole timeout duration before giving up, because it expects to find the element. E.g. you have to use `should have_no_content` instead of `should_not have_content`.

Comment: @Marc-AndréLafortune, that's interesting - didn't realise that. Handy to know!

Comment: `expect(page).not_to have_selector("#some_element", visible: true)` worked fine for me using `javascript_driver`, without waiting the whole timeout duration.

Comment: Scratch that. I'm having some awful race condition now.

Comment: Okay, apparently sometimes you have to wait for the page to load before using `have_selector`. I used `find()` with some arbitrary element on the page. I remember having this issue before. My fix feels slightly like a hack, but I don't know of a better solution.

Comment: Updated method for second assertion, as @Marc-AndréLafortune correctly pointed out.

Comment: Actually, since my comment, this has been changed and you can (and should) use `should_not` now, sorry!

Comment: If you specify 'visible: :hidden` that will only match elements on the page that are not visible so you only need one assert/expectation.

Answer (score 10):

**What visible means is not obvious**

The failure may come from a misunderstanding of what is considered visible or not as it is non-obvious, not driver portable, and under-documented. Some tests:

HTML:

```
<div id="visible-empty"                                                                   ></div>
<div id="visible-empty-background"      style="width:10px; height:10px; background:black;"></div>
<div id="visible-empty-background-same" style="width:10px; height:10px; background:white;"></div>
<div id="visible-visibility-hidden"     style="visibility:hidden;"                        >a</div>
<div id="visible-display-none"          style="display:none;"                             >a</div>
```

The only thing Rack test considers as invisible is inline `display: none` (not internal CSS since it does not do selectors):

```
!all('#visible-empty',                 visible: true).empty? or raise
!all('#visible-empty-background',      visible: true).empty? or raise
!all('#visible-empty-background-same', visible: true).empty? or raise
!all('#visible-visibiility-hidden',    visible: true).empty? or raise
 all('#visible-display-none',          visible: true).empty? or raise
```

Poltergeist has a similar behavior, but it can deal with internal CSS and Js `style.display` manipulation:

```
Capybara.current_driver = :poltergeist
!all('#visible-empty',                 visible: true).empty? or raise
!all('#visible-empty-background',      visible: true).empty? or raise
!all('#visible-empty-background-same', visible: true).empty? or raise
!all('#visible-visibiility-hidden',    visible: true).empty? or raise
 all('#visible-display-none',          visible: true).empty? or raise
```

Selenium behaves quite differently: if considers an empty element invisible and `visibility-hidden` as well as `display: none`:

```
Capybara.current_driver = :selenium
 all('#visible-empty',                 visible: true).empty? or raise
!all('#visible-empty-background',      visible: true).empty? or raise
!all('#visible-empty-background-same', visible: true).empty? or raise
 all('#visible-visibiility-hidden',    visible: true).empty? or raise
 all('#visible-display-none',          visible: true).empty? or raise
```

Another common catch is the default value of `visible`:

- it used to be `false` (sees **both** visible and invisible elements),
- currently is `true`
- is controlled by the `Capybara.ignore_hidden_elements` option.

[Reference](http://www.elabs.se/blog/60-introducing-capybara-2-1).

Full runnable test [on my GitHub](https://github.com/cirosantilli/ruby-cheat/blob/f2bbc981147fec1630e29b742a1a9fa215bc3709/capybara/main.rb#L234).

Comment: Great answer - thanks for the effort you put into this. Testing visibility of elements in a suite using multiple drivers is non-trivial.

Comment: "it used to be false (sees both visible and invisible elements), currently is true, and is controlled by the Capybara.ignore_hidden_elements option."
See this blog post for more info:
http://www.elabs.se/blog/60-introducing-capybara-2-1

Answer (score 9):

Using:

```
 Ruby:     ruby 1.9.3dev (2011-09-23 revision 33323) [i686-linux]
 Rails:    3.2.9
 Capybara: 2.0.3
```

I have a Rails application in which there is a link which when clicked should submit an AJAX post request and return a JS response.

Link code:

```
 link_to("Send Notification", notification_path(user_id: user_id), remote: true, method: :post)
```

The JS response (.js.haml file) should toggle the following hidden div on the page the link exists:

```
 #notification_status(style='display:none')
```

**js.haml file contents:**

```
:plain
  var notificationStatusContainer = $('#notification_status');
  notificationStatusContainer.val("#{@notification_status_msg}");
  notificationStatusContainer.show();
```

I was testing my scenario of sending notification and displaying the
notification status message to the user using Cucumber (*cucumber-rails gem with built in
Capybara support*)

I was trying to test that the element having id: **notification_status** was visible
on successful response in my step definition.For this I tried following statements:

```
page.find('#notification_status').should be_visible
page.should have_selector('#notification_status', visible: true)
page.should have_css('#notification_status', visible: true)
page.find('#notification_status', visible: true)
page.find(:css, 'div#notification_status', visible: true)
```

Neither of above worked for me and failed my step.Out of the above listed 5 snippets
the last 4 failed with following error:

```
'expected to find css "#notification_status" but there were no matches. Also found "", which matched the selector but not all filters. (Capybara::ExpectationNotMet)'
```

which was strange because following statement was passing correctly:

```
page.has_selector?('#notification_status')
```

And in fact I inspected the page source using

```
  print page.html
```

which showed up

```
<div style='' id='notification_status'></div>
```

which was expected.

Finally I found this link [capybara assert attributes of an element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5153550/capybara-assert-attributes-of-an-element) which showed up how to inspect an element's attribute in raw manner.

**Also I found in Capybara documentation for visible? method (http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Element#visible%3F-instance_method)
following information:**

```
 Not all drivers support CSS, so the result may be inaccurate.
```

Thus I came to the conclusion that when testing visibility of an element
do not rely on results of Capybara's visible? method when using a CSS selector
and using the solution suggested in link [capybara assert attributes of an element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5153550/capybara-assert-attributes-of-an-element)

I came up with following:

```
 module CustomMatchers
   def should_be_visible(css_selector)
    find(css_selector)['style'].should_not include('display:none', 'display: none')
   end
 end

 World(CustomMatchers)
```

Usage:

```
should_be_visible('#notification_status')
```

Answer (score 5):

You might want to look at [this post](http://www.webcitation.org/68jfoNAWt), which gives a sample method for waiting until all ajax requests are complete:

```
def wait_for_ajax(timeout = Capybara.default_wait_time)
  page.wait_until(timeout) do
    page.evaluate_script 'jQuery.active == 0'
  end
end
```

Comment: This solution is not future compatible, as `wait_until` was [removed from Capybara 2](http://www.elabs.se/blog/53-why-wait_until-was-removed-from-capybara).

Comment: Use `Timeout.timeout`

Comment: Better use `Selenium::WebDriver::Wait`

Comment: if you use selenium only

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer is a bit outdated now as 'should' is deprecated syntax. These days you'd be better off doing something along the lines of `expect(page).not_to have_css('#blah', visible: :hidden)`

Answer (score 1):

The other answers on here are the best way to "wait" for the element. However I have found this didn't work for the site I am working on. Basically the element that needed clicking was visible before the function behind that was fully loaded. This is in fractions of a second but I found my test ran so quick on occasion that it clicked the button and nothing happened. I managed to work around it by doing this make-shift boolean expression:

```
if page.has_selector?('<css-that-appears-after-click>')
  puts ('<Some-message-you-want-printed-in-the-output>')
else
  find('<css-for-the-button-to-click-again>', :match == :first).trigger('click')
end
```

Basically it uses the capybara default wait time to look for something that should appear, if it isnt there it will retry your click.

Again I will say that the `should have_selector` method should be tried first but if it just wont work try this