# How to add a wait method to wait until a specific element is loaded in ruby+Cucumber2.0

Tags: ruby, rspec, cucumber, capybara

I have a problem while testing my cases on browser stack. The problem am facing is inconsistently reproduced.

To make my code wait until an element is loaded am using as below:

```
gift_no_btn1 = Capybara.find('giftingNoButton')
gift_no_btn1.click
```

The problem here is that the screen is stuck in the other module where my intended element is not loaded and hence my script fails. I have read that find() method is replaced of wait_untill method in Capybara 2.0.

Comment: Have you looked at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8801845/how-to-make-capybara-check-for-visibility-after-some-js-has-run ? Note the :js => true setting

Comment: Yes, i did. But its not helpful

Comment: Can you post the error log?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Capybaras find methods will wait up to Capybara.default_max_wait_time seconds for a matching element to appear.  If they are not waiting long enough either increase that setting or override it for a specific find with the :wait option like

```
page.find :css, 'CSS selector for the element', wait: 10
```

which will wait up to 10 seconds for the element to exist.  In your example you're passing a CSS selector of 'giftingNoButton' which isn't really valid unless you're using custom elements. You probably want '#giftingNoButton' (find id matching) or '.giftingNoButton' (class matching)