# Ambiguous match, found 2 elements matching css - Capybara

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I have a test that renders two of the same elements on the page. I understand what the problem is with the error but I'm just not sure how to fix it? Here is my test:

### TEST

```
 it "deletes the correct snitch" do
        user    = login_user
        snitch  = create(:snitch, :healthy, owner: user.accounts.first)
        snitch2 = create(:snitch, :healthy, owner: user.accounts.first)

        visit root_path
        delete = page.find(".icon-delete")
        first(delete).click
        expect(page).to have_content("Please confirm this delete.")


 end
```

### ERROR

```
 Managing snitches deleting a snitch from the index page deletes the correct snitch
 Failure/Error: delete = page.find(".icon-delete")

 Capybara::Ambiguous:
   Ambiguous match, found 2 elements matching css ".icon-delete"
```

How can I pick just one of the icon delete on the page?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I would suggest wrapping it in a more specific finder as below:

```
within find('#my_unique_id') do
  find(".icon-delete").click
end
```

That however would require you to have an id on the parent element. If you don't have this, you could go the simple route of selecting the first one on that page then calling click on that:

```
first(".icon-delete").click
```

Comment: this solution skips the amazing automatic waiting feature that Capybara has, though

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39859291/how-to-add-a-wait-method-to-wait-until-a-specific-element-is-loaded-in-rubycucu

Answer (score 11):

```rb
click_on "Link Text.", match: :first
```

Answer (score 8):

First takes the same parameters as find (not elements) so to just click on the first matching element you would do

```
page.first('.icon-delete').click
```

There is a difference to take into account though, since nil is a valid response for first it won't (by default) wait for a matching element to appear.  If you do need it to wait for the element you just need to pass one of the count options

```
page.first('.icon-delete', minimum: 1).click
```