# Rails Capybara not detecting vivsiblity of flex item

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, capybara

I am doing `display: flex` an element on button click and then `display: none` to the same element after some ajax calls. I am doing the integration testing for the same using `Capybara` with `Selenium` driver. The problem is that capybara detects the visibility of the element and sometimes it does not even though the element is visible. I have tried giving different `wait` values but still it works sometimes and sometimes it does not. Is there anyway I can rectify this? The code is as below:

```
ele.addEventListener('change', () => {
  showSpinner(true);
  ajaxCall().then(() => showSpinner(false));
}

showSpinner = (flag) => {
  let spinner = document.getElementById('spinner');
  if (!spinner) {
    return;
  } else if (flag) {
    spinner.classList.add('show');
  } else {
    spinner.classList.remove('show');
  }
};

.spinner.show {
  display: flex;
}

.spinner {
  display: none;
  // other properties
}
```

In test file

```
choose 'radio_button' // if radio button
select 'some text', from: 'dropdown_element' // if dropdown
assert page.has_css?('.spinner', wait: 0)
```

This works sometimes and sometimes it does not. The element is selected or clicked. That works. But not `has_css`. Also I tried using `assert_css` but I am getting error. So how can I write the testcase for the above problem?

Comment: What error do you get with `assert_css` because you REALLY REALLY REALLY shouldn't be using bare `assert` with Capybara predicates.  If it's that the method doesn't exist it's probably because you haven't required `capybara/minitest` (assuming you are using minitest)

Comment: Yes. That method does not exist. I haven't required `capybara/minintest`. I will do that but why should I not use `assert` and why is `assert_css` preferred over the former?

Comment: because it leads to writing more stable tests (retrying behavior), and because the errors will actually be useful when an assertion does fail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem as below. I found the answer from a comment by @Thomas Walpole for this question [Check element visibility that is visible for less than a second in Rails Capybara](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59775329/check-element-visibility-that-is-visible-for-less-than-a-second-in-rails-capybar) asked by me. The problem was that sometimes the ajax response was very fast and sometimes it was slow. So all I had to was to slow down the network.

```
// Set the latency time through selenium before the click or select and then check 
// for the visibility of the element on page and then again change back the latency

page.driver.browser.network_conditions = { offline: false, latency: 2000, throughput: 789 }
choose 'radio_button' // if radio button
select 'some text', from: 'dropdown_element' // if dropdown
assert page.has_css?('.spinner', wait: 0)
page.driver.browser.network_conditions = { offline: false, latency: 0, throughput: 0 }
// continue with other tests
```

This worked for my problem. Feel free to improve this solution.