# How do I confirm a css element attribute with Capybara?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

This may seem unusually basic but how do I confirm the presence of a pop up confirmation?

```
<a data-confirm="delete this video?" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/videos/21">Delete</a>
```

`<a` is the "tag"/"element" and `data-confirm` is an attribute. I want to test for the existence of the "data-confirm" attribute within the `<a>` element/tag

I have tried

```
expect(page).to have_css("a.data-confirm.delete this video?")
```

from

[capybara assert attributes of an element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5153550/capybara-assert-attributes-of-an-element?rq=1)
but no joy.

Edit:

I've tried the expectation from Arup's comment below

```
expect(page).to have_content "Content"
click_link "Delete"
expect(page).to have_css('a[data-confirm="delete this video?"]')
```

But it raises the following (same) error

```
Failures:

1) Visiting the video index page should search and save movies
 Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_css('a[data-confirm="delete this video?"]')
   expected #has_css?("a[data-confirm=\"delete this video?\"]") to return true, got false
```

but the page source shows it there and it is clearly working for the user

Any assistance would be very appreciated

Comment: Don't edit the question with the answer like that. Of you did, add it as an *update* without removing the actual post. Now it seems to everyone I wrote an answer which is what you tried on the first place and it didn't work. That said, the expectation syntax is correct, but it is failing due to other reason which can be answered by looking at your actual environment.

Comment: Oh, yeah okay. I've made a bit of a mess now haven't I? Feel free to edit the original post. with a reputation like 87k I guess you have the privileges.

Comment: @Arup What element(s) of the environment would I need to be looking for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write this expectation as:

```
expect(page).to have_css('a[data-confirm="delete this video?"]')
```

Comment: Thanks @Arup Rakshit I've updated my question to reflect your comment. But I still can't make it work?

Comment: I don't understand why it's failing? it is only this one expectation that I can not run. And your solution is the only reference to it I can find anywhere on the WWW. How did you know the syntax?

Comment: Okay. Placing Arups line prior to the delete link being clicked works!?! I would have expected confirmation of the 'pop-up' notification to occur after it was raised? Oh well... 4 hours of frustration later I at least know how to test for element attributes with Rspec and Capybara. Thanks Arup

Comment: @JustMattfornow It is a normal, valid CSS rule I wrote with Capybara. :)

Answer (score 1):

The answer by Arup is correct for the title of the question (and as he stated in the comments it's just valid CSS - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors), however it's not actually testing the more detailed part of the question "how do I confirm the presence of a pop up confirmation".  All it is doing is confirming the correct data attribute is on the link element to trigger the rails provided JS that should show a confirm.

If you wanted to actually test the confirm box is shown you would need to swap to using a JS capable driver - https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/tree/2.17_stable#drivers - and then use something like the following in your test

```
expect(page).to have_content "Content"
accept_confirm "delete this video?" do
  click_link "Delete" # The action that will make the system modal confirm box appear
end
```

See - http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/capybara/Capybara/Session#accept_confirm-instance_method

Comment: Ahh... Yeah, absolutely right. The question doesn't reflect the actual problem. Damn! You solved the problem but Arup _technically_ answered the question. (which was still a problem, just not, as you have now illuminated, _the_ problem). Note the reputation number next to my avatar and beware "Newb at large!" Thanks a heap! testing popups is fairly fundamental.